# how to transition a multiseries line chart to a new dataset

Tags: d3.js

I could really use some guidance setting up a transition on my multiseries line chart. As an example of what I need, I've started with this great multiseries line chart: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955. To that code, I've added an update() function that's called once using setInterval(). I've also created a new data set called data2.csv which is similar to data.tsv but has different values.

The update function should change the data that the line chart is displaying. Forget about making a nice smooth transition, I can't even get the data to update in the chart view. When I try using the update function, it looks like the new data is loaded properly into the javascript variables, but the lines on the chart don't change at all.

I've seen variations on this question asked a few times but haven't found an answer yet. Can anyone help me figure out how to transition this multi-series line chart to a new dataset (also multiseries)?

```
function update() {

    d3.csv("data2.csv", function(error, data) {

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

        // format the date
   data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

    // rearrange the data, same as in the original example code
var cities2 = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name]};
          })
        };
      });

    // update the .city g's to the new dataset
 var city2 = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities2);

    // redraw the lines with the new data??? 
  city2.selectAll("path")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

 clearInterval(transitionInterval);
});
}
```

**UPDATE**: NikhilS's answer contains the key to the solution in the comment trail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure you are following the enter + update process as outlined by Mike Bostock in his stuff on the [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234). It looks like you haven't invoked any kind of d3 `transition`. You also haven't specified an enter or exit for the update function, which will cause problems if you have new data coming in and/or old data going out. Try changing this:

```
 var city2 = svg.selectAll(".city")
  .data(cities2);

 city2.selectAll("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });
```

to the following:

```
 var city2 = svg.selectAll('.city')
   .data(cities2);

 var cityGroups = city2.enter().append('g')
   .attr('class', 'city');

 cityGroups.append('path')
  .attr('class', 'line');

 d3.transition().selectAll('.line')
  .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.values); });

 city2.exit().remove();
```

I made a basic data re-join and update demo a while back, which you can [view here](http://tributary.io/inlet/5127223).

Comment: Hi NikhilS, Thanks for your advice and your tutorial. I hadn't included the full enter + update because I know the new dataset has the same exact number of entries as the original, so the enter and exit selections will be empty. In any case, I've added your suggestions for good practice, and I've taken a look at your tutorial.

Comment: But still, the data doesn't change onscreen. When I step through the code, cities2 looks good, and the data for the city2 selection is updated, but the d attr for the paths doesn't get updated in the DOM. Checking the console, it looks like the data for the paths is still the original data, while the data for the 'g's is the new data. Should there be some additional call like this: 'd3.transition().selectAll("path").data(cities2)'?

Comment: Ok. Try rewriting the `update()` function so that it accepts a dataset as an argument (as it is in the small example I posted). Run it once with the first dataset passed in, then later with the second. This is also better from a DRY perspective. If that doesn't work try posting on jsfiddle or tributary and I can take a closer look.

Comment: Thanks again for sticking with me. I rewrote update() to accept dataset as an argument and used it only for the second dataset. I'm not quite sure it makes sense for the first dataset -- there's a lot of graph set up that wouldn't need to be repeated for the second dataset, and ultimately I'm going to have many transitions between a number of datasets so the setup code would run once and the update code would run a number of times.

Comment: Here's a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BkSBK/). (I'm new to fiddle so let me know if it doesn't work). I added a title so you can see the update code is getting called, and created local datasets. Still, the lines don't change at the transition.

Comment: Alright, I got it working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YPBjj/). First I moved everything data-driven to the `update` function. I still had some trouble getting things to update, which I solved by using `var cityUpdate = d3.transition(cities)`, then updating the value with `cityUpdate.select('path').attr(...)`. You can see in the code.

Comment: Thank you @NikhilS! I don't think I could've solved this on my own. I am very grateful!! Carrie

Comment: @nsonnad, could you edit your answer to include this? Took me a few minutes to realize the real answer was buried in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

use d3 Transition, you can make some sort of animation.

If you want to select a sub-interval of the data to plot the graph, no need manipulation on the data, just use a d3 brush and clip the graph

For a multi-series line graph with most of the line graph elements, you could refer to this example: http://mpf.vis.ywng.cloudbees.net/